Python 3.12.3 Quart Hypercorn doesn't run / configure properly through programmtically loading .toml file
I tried to load .toml config file programmatically but it doesn't work:
from hypercorn.config import Config
config = Config()
config.from_toml("/etc/pythonrestapi.toml")

asyncio.run(serve(app, config))

This is all I see in the terminal when running it through pipenv run hypercorn --reload src.main:app:
[2024-06-01 11:28:40 +0800] [100003] [INFO] Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (CTRL + C to quit)
2024-06-01 11:28:40 INFO     Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (CTRL + C to quit)


You are mixing two independent methods of running Hypercorn - the command line and API. If you want to run the python code you've shown then use python on the command line.
